# I am getting CALL_EXCEPTION error on mainnet. I am trying to sell my own token cls token with usdt

Tags: solidity, metamask, ethers.js, usdt, tether

I can't understand why the error occurs. I wonder if I need other permissions to use the usdt token. So I wonder if I can't buy tether (usdt) with my own erc20 token, what is preventing this?

Solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT LICENSE

pragma solidity 0.8.11;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract CLSICO is Ownable {
    
    address payable public wallet;
    uint256 public rate;
    uint256 public weiRaised;
    uint256 public usdtBalance;

    address public constant usdtTokenAddress = 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7; //0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7
    address public constant clsTokenAddress = 0x1D06a839cDE5b669084fA50f210BC004e07d04A1; 

    IERC20 public usdtToken;
    IERC20 public clsToken;

    event TokensPurchased(address indexed purchaser, address indexed beneficiary, uint256 value, uint256 amount);

    constructor(address payable _wallet, uint256 _rate) {
        require(_wallet != address(0), "Invalid wallet address");
        require(_rate > 0, "Invalid rate");
        wallet = _wallet;
        rate = _rate;
        usdtToken = IERC20(usdtTokenAddress);
        clsToken = IERC20(clsTokenAddress);
        usdtBalance = 0;
    }

    function buyTokens(address payable _beneficiary, uint256 usdtAmount) public payable {

        require(_beneficiary != address(0), "Invalid beneficiary address");
        require(usdtAmount > 0, "Invalid amount of USDT");

        // CLS token amount calculate
        uint256 clsAmount = usdtAmount * rate;
        
        // USDT transfer
        usdtToken.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(usdtToken.approve(address(this), usdtAmount), "USDT approval failed");
        require(usdtToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, wallet, usdtAmount), "USDT transfer failed");
        usdtBalance += usdtAmount;

        // CLS transfer
        clsToken.allowance(wallet, address(this));
        require(clsToken.approve(address(this), clsAmount), "CLS approval failed");
        require(clsToken.transferFrom(wallet, _beneficiary, clsAmount), "CLS transfer failed");

        emit TokensPurchased(msg.sender, _beneficiary, usdtAmount, clsAmount);

    }

    function setRate(uint256 newRate) public onlyOwner {
        require(newRate > 0, "Invalid rate");
        rate = newRate;
    }
    
    function withdrawUSDT(uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        require(usdtBalance >= amount, "Insufficient USDT balance");
        require(usdtToken.transfer(wallet, amount), "USDT withdrawal failed");

        // USDT balance update
        usdtBalance -= amount;
    }
}
```

Can you tell if the problem is caused by ethers.js, by gas Limit, or is it an error in my contract?

Ethers.js

```
const handleSwap  = async () => {
    try {
      const web3Modal = new Web3Modal()
      const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
      const signer = provider.getSigner()
      let tether = new ethers.Contract(mmusdt,USDT,signer)
      let cls = new ethers.Contract(mmcls,CLS,signer)
      let contractico = new ethers.Contract(mmico, ICO, signer)
      console.log("usdtvalue",usdtValue)
      let price = new ethers.utils.parseUnits(usdtValue, 'ether')
      price = price.toString()

      await tether.approve(mmico,price)

      await contractico.buyTokens(selectedAddress, price,{gasLimit:500000}).then(data => console.log(data)) 
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error",err)
    }
  }
```

I am trading with a brand new metamask wallet, first of all, tether approve function works. In buyTokens function, I get CALL_EXCEPTION or UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT , cannot estimate gas errors

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be related to the way you are handling token allowances and approvals in your Solidity contract. In the buyTokens function, you are calling `usdtToken.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));`
and `clsToken.allowance(wallet, address(this));`
but you are not using the returned values.

You should check if the allowances are sufficient before proceeding with the token transfers.

Here's an updated version of your buyTokens function:

```
function buyTokens(address payable _beneficiary, uint256 usdtAmount) public payable {

    require(_beneficiary != address(0), "Invalid beneficiary address");
    require(usdtAmount > 0, "Invalid amount of USDT");

    // CLS token amount calculate
    uint256 clsAmount = usdtAmount * rate;

    // Check USDT allowance
    uint256 usdtAllowance = usdtToken.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
    require(usdtAllowance >= usdtAmount, "Insufficient USDT allowance");

    // USDT transfer
    require(usdtToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, wallet, usdtAmount), "USDT transfer failed");
    usdtBalance += usdtAmount;

    // Check CLS allowance
    uint256 clsAllowance = clsToken.allowance(wallet, address(this));
    require(clsAllowance >= clsAmount, "Insufficient CLS allowance");

    // CLS transfer
    require(clsToken.transferFrom(wallet, _beneficiary, clsAmount), "CLS transfer failed");

    emit TokensPurchased(msg.sender, _beneficiary, usdtAmount, clsAmount);
}
```

In this updated version, remove the unnecessary approve calls and added checks for sufficient allowances before transferring tokens.
Additionally, in your Ethers.js code, you are using `ethers.utils.parseUnits(usdtValue, 'ether')` to convert the USDT value to a BigNumber.

However, USDT has 6 decimal places, not 18 like Ether.

You should change this line to:

```
let price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(usdtValue, 6);
```

After making these changes, your contract should work as expected. If you still encounter issues, please ensure that you have enough USDT and CLS tokens in the respective wallets and that you have set the correct allowances for the contract.

Comment: Also, I usually swap with WETH in the code, and the gas limit will be not more than 500k as you set. I think <300k is enough for your token purchase. Instead, you should set MaxFeePerGas more high.